# Wrong assignment to struct

Tags: c++, struct, variable-assignment

I have structs like this:

```cpp
typedef struct ws2811_channel_t
{
    int gpionum;                                 //< GPIO Pin with PWM alternate function, 0 if unused
    int invert;                                  //< Invert output signal
    int count;                                   //< Number of LEDs, 0 if channel is unused
    int strip_type;                              //< Strip color layout -- one of WS2811_STRIP_xxx constants
    ws2811_led_t *leds;                          //< LED buffers, allocated by driver based on count
    uint8_t brightness;                          //< Brightness value between 0 and 255
    uint8_t wshift;                              //< White shift value
    uint8_t rshift;                              //< Red shift value
    uint8_t gshift;                              //< Green shift value
    uint8_t bshift;                              //< Blue shift value
    uint8_t *gamma;                              //< Gamma correction table
} ws2811_channel_t;

typedef struct ws2811_t
{
    uint64_t render_wait_time;                   //< time in µs before the next render can run
    struct ws2811_device *device;                //< Private data for driver use
    const rpi_hw_t *rpi_hw;                      //< RPI Hardware Information
    uint32_t freq;                               //< Required output frequency
    int dmanum;                                  //< DMA number _not_ already in use
    ws2811_channel_t channel[RPI_PWM_CHANNELS];
} ws2811_t;
```

and my working example:

```cpp
ws2811_channel_t channel = {
        .gpionum = LED_PIN,
        .invert = LED_INVERT,
        .count = LED_COUNT,
        .strip_type = WS2811_STRIP_RGB,
        .brightness = LED_BRIGHTNESS,

    };
    ws2811_t test = {
        .freq = LED_FREQ_HZ,
        .dmanum = LED_DMA,
        channel,
    };
    LOG_INFO("LEDController: Init - " << ws2811_get_return_t_str(ws2811_init(&test)));
    for (int i = 0; i < LED_COUNT; i++)
    {
        test.channel[0].leds[i] = (0 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 0;
    
    }
    ws2811_render(&test);
```

I want to make proper assignment for private property in class, so when I am declaring it like this:

```cpp
ws2811_channel_t channel;
channel.gpionum = LED_PIN;
channel.invert = LED_INVERT;
channel.count = LED_COUNT;
channel.strip_type = WS2811_STRIP_RGB;
channel.brightness = LED_BRIGHTNESS;
ws2811_t test;
test.freq = LED_FREQ_HZ;
test.dmanum = LED_DMA;
test.channel[0] = channel;

    LOG_INFO("LEDController: Init - " << ws2811_get_return_t_str(ws2811_init(&test)));
    for (int i = 0; i < LED_COUNT; i++)
    {
        test.channel[0].leds[i] = (0 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 0;
    
    }
ws2811_render(&test);
```

`ws2811_render(&test);` hangs and freezes, on some point I got error which was pointing to that method.
I am assuming it's because it has wrong assignments somehow. But why?

definition of render is

```
ws2811_return_t  ws2811_render(ws2811_t *ws2811)
```

From here: https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x/blob/master/ws2811.c#L1138

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ws2811_render(&test);` the bug could be the &. Also do you now have a c++ compiler that supports the new c++20 `ws2811_channel_t channel = {  .gpionum = LED_PIN,` ? [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers)

Comment: Please add the definition of `ws2811_render`.

Comment: @drescherjm C supports that syntax. It's possible that OP is using a C++ compiler that supports it as an extension.

Comment: definition of render is here https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x/blob/master/ws2811.c#L1138
looks like I have C++20, because it works with the new assignment. but I want to do it old way. I  will have to. but I am having hard times with it

Comment: The `test.channel[0].leds[i] = (0 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 0;` loop (looks like a funny way to zero-initialize the `leds` array) doesn't seem to have an equivalent in the second code. So the final `test.channel[0].leds` data will be uninitialized. I think.

Comment: Yes it zeros them it's like that only because I was testing different values. But essentially it doesn't matter, because it all leds = 0 then that's switching them off.

Comment: But you don't zero them in the second code, that I can see. Where do you think that is being done?

Comment: second code it's just assignment part, rest stays the same (for loop)

Comment: OK - are the `channel` elements other than the `[0]` elements being used? First code will zero-fill the rest of the array; second code won't touch anything but element 0.

Comment: I would do `extern "C" {` ... `}` around the `#include` of the header file declaring `ws2811_render()` etc. Edit: It's not needed. the header file has that already.

Comment: In your second example, try `ws2811_channel_t channel{};` and `ws2811_t test{};` - e.g. add the `{}`.

Comment: Note that the fact that a program's appearing to work is only *very* weak evidence that it's not fundamentally broken.

Comment: when I do `ws2811_channel_t channel{};` I get segmentation fault

Comment: Did you do that for both channel _and_ test?

Comment: yes, it stops straight at `ws2811_channel_t channel{};` Actually ignore me ...I messed up something else on the way. AND IT WORKS ! 
Why is that ?

Comment: As I said before, you should use C, not C++, with this C library, until you have a firmer understanding of both languages.

Comment: That's not an option I am afraid. I have Cpp program that I didn't write, and need to adapt that C library to it. There is no working Cpp library of that kind. So that's my only way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example, try `ws2811_channel_t channel{};` and `ws2811_t test{};` - e.g. add the `{}`.

If you do this, then you'll *zero* initialise all the members. The key difference between your first (working) version, and the second (broken) version is that first version will zero things like `gamma` whilst the second version won't. Adding `{}` will zero everything before you overwrite the items you want.

If you do `type a = {...}`, then whatever is in the `...` and *not* mentioned or indexed will be *zeroed*. If you do `type b; b.field=value;` there is nothing here that will zero any specifically not initialised fields.

Comment: That works. Thank you so much. Could you briefly explain why ?